# Fast refresh kill auth in laravel. How to fix?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new in laravel. I faced up problem with session in laravel. I have a page with a dozens of goods. But its not a problem, problem rise when I press F5 button - the user auth is out. That not depends from a time. I can just press F5 (hold down) and in a few seconds user is logout. Config in /app/config/session.php is default. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Auth::attempt method with the optional input of "remember me" set to true.

**Note:** Make sure your Users table in database has a column named "remember_token" with at least 100 characters available.

Comment: Yep, now user stay in my matrix for a while ;) can you explain in two words why user is logout on fast page refreshing ?

Comment: sorry but I couldn't reproduce the problem. can you please provide more information to reproduce that?

Comment: try to fill a few tables with info (50-100 rows) and to select info from them on one page via joins or something like that (need to load database). Then press F5 and hold down it. if "remember me" in auth not set up - user must log out.

Comment: There are two possibilities, since I don't know your code. If you are using the built in csrf tokens and using it in your forms, then each form must comply with its corresponding csrf token and by fast refreshing you mess them up.
The second one is that by refreshing, since your code waits for DB to respond, it doesn't return properly. If Laravel app doesn't return properly, it won't write anything in session; this is because Laravel uses Symphony. So it thinks this is a fresh session. Since "remember me" forces writing cookie, even with a fresh session, it can "remember" the user.

Comment: yep, I think the second one. Thank you